# Is it possible to get the timing of phonemes with Vosk, instead of full words?

Tags: vosk

Vosk outputs the timing of words well, but for syllables / phonemes within words, does Vosk have an option or technique to split the output by those instead?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a technique to do this. There are [pull requests](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/pull/528) that add this functionality for phonemes, so if necessary you could build from their source.